# unable to install o/s after hard drive replacement

Tags: windows-10, uefi

I recently started getting hard drive error messages in event viewer.  I have an Acer Aspire v5-571 notebook running Windows 10 pro.  I replaced the drive, and then put my trusty USB boot key with ghost on it.  Notebook will not boot from USB, of even DVD.  It goes straight into no operating system.  I already know about how UEFI and secure boot like to prevent damage, so I checked the BIOS to make sure Secure Boot was NOT enabled.  It was not enabled.  The only way I can get it to boot from USB or DVD is to disable UEFI completely.  Doing that allows me to boot from USB, and also lets me ghost my old drive onto this new drive.  Now the issue is it will not boot into windows afterwards.  It still comes back with no operating system.  My original Windows was running from a drive that was running under UEFI.  Since I cannot boot from non hard drives when UEFI is enabled, I cannot install Windows from DVD or USB when UEFI is enabled.  How the hell did windows ever get installed in the first place?
I have tried all the various suggestions from other threads with no success.  I cannot run the various built in windows tools from install windows DVD due to famous drive locked error message.  I get the drive locked error after using ghost to transfer my old drive contents to new drive, and then running DVD to get install tools to fix windows I startup files.

This used to be something you could do in your sleep.  I know I can simply re-partition the drive in order to do a clean windows install, but I really would rather get my original version back.

Comment: What is your question?